# Is it possible to apply versioning on just data.sql and not schema.sql for Flyway in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to use Flyway. I understand that it is used for migration purposes. My use case is to load data from data.sql in my classpath. And I will want to add more data so I will need another data.sql file in future.

Is it possible to version just the data.sql file using Flyway? I am using Spring Boot to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

it might be worth while starting with the Flyway Migrate documentation to help with understanding Flyway versioning scripts and naming conventions.
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations

Comment: It doesn't say anything about insert scripts but rather schema changes. I am wondering if insert scripts can be versioned. But it looks like insert scripts are not meant to be versioned.

Comment: If you look at the example in https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#versioned-migrations there is an insert statement. Although the idea is that Flyway will be used to maintain schema structure changes, you can use version migrations to version control insert statements into a database

Comment: Here again, a new table is created and then inserted values. I tried to add just an insert or an update of the existing data, and both did not work.

Comment: “Did not work” is unhelpful without further detail. What command did you run, what did you expect and what happened?